# Pandas compare value with previous row and change the values of the remaining rows in a grouped dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of machines. Dataframe is grouped by serial number and sorted by date. the value of each column is increasing in each group of serial numbers (machines). Dataframe look likes this

Dataframe:

```
    serial_number   eng_hr  lifts   tons   km           date_created
6173    A1          31      50      700    10           2014-10-22
6152    A1          32      55      800    20           2015-09-10
6159    A1          33      60      900    30           2015-09-23
7070    A2          20      30      150    500          2014-04-23
7016    A2          25      40      160    600          2014-08-28
7055    A2          30      50      170    700          2014-10-28
7011    A2          35      60      180    800          2014-11-13
2189    A3          10      20      10     100          2015-03-12
2239    A3          20      30      20     200          2015-03-12
2225    A3          30      40      30     300          2015-03-23
```

However, there are some cases that the difference of current row value and the next row is less than 0 as you can see in the line X+1 = 1573 and X = 1541 in the below table (it is happening in lifts, tons and km). this table is details of a machine sorted by date. resulted by: `df[df['serial_number']=='A5'][['serial_number','eng_hr','lifts','tons','km','date_created']]` :

```
      serial_number eng_hr      lifts   tons    km          date_created

1573    A5          10          50      200     20          2017-02-23
1541    A5          20          60      300     25          2017-03-17
1574    A5          30          20      100     5           2017-06-14
1553    A5          40          30      200     10          2017-08-16
1552    A5          50          40      300     15          2017-08-28
1554    A5          60          50      400     20          2017-09-22
1556    A5          70          60      500     30          2017-10-09
1550    A5          80          70      600     40          2018-12-03
1564    A5          90          80      700     50          2019-04-18
```

In this case, I need to add the value of the current row (row number 1541) to all next rows of the dataframe in those specific attributes. So previous table should look like this (changes are happening from row number 1574 in lifts, tones, and km):

```
      serial_number eng_hr      lifts   tons    km          date_created

1573    A5          10          50      200     20          2017-02-23
1541    A5          20          60      300     25          2017-03-17
1574    A5          30          80      400     30          2017-06-14
1553    A5          40          90      500     35          2017-08-16
1552    A5          50          100     600     40          2017-08-28
1554    A5          60          110     700     45          2017-09-22
1556    A5          70          120     800     55          2017-10-09
1550    A5          80          130     900     65          2018-12-03
1564    A5          90          140     1000    75          2019-04-18
```

How can I do it with Pandas?

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for you contingent on your problem behaving exactly as you describe (i.e. if for a given serial number, there is one adjustment that needs to be made, and that adjustment is ordered as you've described, this should work.) This may not be generalizable, or be the most efficient fix, but it should work.

I First define a function that takes a dataframe, and list of columns as parameters. Line by line the function opperates as follows:

1. Resets the index, moving 'machine' into the dataframe as a column
2. Creates a dummy variable 'flag' that equals 1 if there has been a negative change in all columns identified by col (in your example `['lifts','tons','km']`)
3. Uses 'flag' to identify the previous row as the 'fix' (i.e. the row that will be added to the others)
4. Flags the portion of the dataframe that needs the adjustment
5. Adds the relevant column information from 'fix' to the flagged portion of the dataframe
6. Pieces the dataframe back together, restores 'machine' as the index, and returns the dataframe

Code:

```
def fixer(x,col):

    x = x.reset_index()
    x['flag'] = 1*((x[col] - x[col].shift())<0).all(axis='columns')
    fix = x[x['flag'].shift(-1) ==1][col]

    flagged = x['flag'].cumsum()>0
    fixed = x[flagged]
    fixed[col] = x[flagged][col].add(fix.values.tolist()[0],axis='columns')

    x = x[~flagged].append(fixed)
    x = x.drop(columns =['flag']).set_index('machine')

    return x
```

When this has been declared you can apply it to each serial_number group in the following manner:

```
df = df.groupby('serial_number').apply(fixer,['lifts','tons','km']).droplevel('serial_number')
```

I hope this helps. Let me know if you run into issues.